# Do I need to add rule for each port that Gitlab listens on?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firewall, port, gitlab

I have a Gitlab server which is an Ubuntu 18.04 virtual machine on VMWare Esxi. I wanted to enable the firewall on this machine, for which purpose I installed `gufw`. The thing is that when I run the `sudo netstat -ntpl | grep LISTEN` command, I can see a number of ports listening. A number of ports are listening because of Gitlab. For example, component Gitlab exporter is listening on port 9168, and there are others as well.

See [a full list of Gitlab ports](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/package-information/defaults.html).

If I switch on the firewall using `gufw`, do I need to add incoming rules for `80 (HTTP)` and `22 (SSH)` only? Or do I need to open for different ports for different components mentioned in the above link?

It is a very simple Gitlab server installation whose purpose is only version control. I don't need advanced features like CI/CD, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, if you're hosting the server in production, and facing the public Internet, you should really only allow the following ports to be accessed from the outside:

- 80/443: Web access via HTTP (`https://gitlab.example.com/`)
- 22: Git access via SSH (`git@gitlab.example.com/…`)

Most of the other ports* are needed GitLab-internally for services to communicate among each other. For example, querying the database, or sending metrics to Prometheus, which is used for internal performance monitoring. But these should not be accessible from the outside, and – if I'm not mistaken – should anyway be bound to the localhost only, so even without setting up a firewall, you should not be able to access them from the outside.

<sub>* The container registry, for example, can be bound to another port so that you can access it with the same hostname, e.g. `gitlab.example.com:5050`, instead of requiring another path.</sub>

Comment: Thanks, it clears the doubt.